# Windows 7 won't start up after clean install

Tags: windows-7, boot

I just installed Windows 7 Ultimate on an Acer M1201. When the installation is done, I see the boot information, my HDD is there but when this info screen goes away, I see the underscore in the upper left hand corner flickering but it won't go thru that point!

I've check the settings in BIOS and everything seems fine. I also disconnected the DVD drive and Windows won't kick in. I don't have any PCI devices also...

Any takers?

Comment: How did you install Windows 7? Did you use a disc provided by Acer, or did you use a retail copy bought in a store?

Also, what operating system did the computer come with?

Comment: Windows Vista OEM came with this computer with a restore partition that I've deleted since two of my software are not compatible with Vista. So I bought a genuine Windows 7 Ultimate from a retailer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow. There could be a host of problems here but I'm leaning towards the Hard Drive failure. Windows needs the boot information from the HD but if it cant get it, it stays there waiting. 
Try disconnecting and reconnecting the HD and if you can try a next HD, who knows what could happen ... *fingers crossed* Hope it works

Comment: That was my next step. I just need to buy a new HDD and I'll try it.

Comment: I changed the HDD and it worked fine.